# Logit versus Probit

Tags: logit, probit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between logit and probit models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/difference-between-logit-and-probit-models)

I have data in which the response variable is binary. So, I fitted logit and probit models and obtained the results. How can I compare them to see which fit is better?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/difference-between-logit-and-probit-models

Comment: Though they produce very different parameters, the fitted curves are usually so close that they often cannot be meaningfully distinguished unless there is something unusual happening in the tails.